# How to assign new identity when using the "advanced" version?

Tags: windows, identity-change, mac

So how do I do this in MacOS Yosemite and Windows 7 ?

In the previous windows releases Tor wasn't running in the background so I could just close the app and run it again. But in the new version when I start the app it stays in the background and I only see it in Task Manager.

Same happens in MacOS, it's only visible in the terminal if I use "ps". Is "killing" it the only way?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options :

- send a `SIGHUP` to tor via `killall -HUP tor`
- setup a `ControlPort` and via telnet control protocol send `SIGNAL NEWNYM`

Answer (score 0):

For your MacOS related query, from the terminal you can send Tor a [HUP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103610/what-does-hup-do-when-used-with-killall) signal to re-read its config files and create a new circuit without actually killing the process: `killall -HUP tor`

See the following thread for a similar discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987518/how-to-request-new-tor-identity-in-terminal